# How Check if site alive and run a script if not in Windows with curl

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Im trying to write a simple script to check if site alive, wait 5 seconds for answer and run a different script if the site is not answering.

For checking the site im using the next curl command:

```
curl.exe -Isf https://www.yahoo.com/ | findstr /I /R "200 301"
```

for the waiting I'm using the "timeout" command.

Unfortunately I was not able to run it well.

---

Hi Gerhard,
Thank you for you answer.
Unfortunately the errorlevel doesnt work well because that when the condition is true, I receive HTTP/1.1 200 OK (For Example), But when the condition isnt true, I receive no answer, unless im using -v (photo attached)

My goal is to check if site is alive and if its alive >>> Exit.
If not >>> run a script.

---- TRUE -----

> curl.exe -Isf "https://www.yahoo.com/" | findstr /IR "200 301"
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

---- NOT True ----
[Not True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGytC.png)

THANKS, I successfully managed to create it in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you only want to run you script if you do not get a response from the site with either `http/1.1 200` or `http/1.1 301`

Simply use `errorlevel`:

```
curl.exe -Isf "https://www.yahoo.com/" | findstr /IR "200 301"
if not errorlevel 0 down_script.cmd
```

Where `down_script.cmd` would be the other script you want to run if site is not available.

alternatively, if you run other commands within the script, simply `goto`

```
curl.exe -Isf "https://www.yahoo.com/" | findstr /IR "200 301"
if not errorlevel 0 goto :SiteDown
goto :eof

:SiteDown
echo here you will do other things if http/1.1 200 or 301 was not met.
```

Additionally, I am a little unceratain why you needed the `timeout` command, as this script will wait for a response from curl before it goes to the next line.